# If $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a sequence of functions s.t. for any n, $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)\leq g(x)$, does $f_n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a sequence of functions s.t. for any $n$, $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)\leq g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is some function on $[0,1]$ does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) $ exist?

I am bit confused about the wording of the question as well. Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) $ refer to pointwise or uniform convergence of the sequence?

Comment: It refers to pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointwise, yes. For each $x$ the sequence $(f_n(x))_n$ is monotonous increasing and bounded, so it converges to some $L_x\leq g(x)$. Defining $l:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $l(x)=L_x$ we see $f_n\rightarrow l$ pointwise.

Uniformly, not necessarily. The counterexample is the sequence $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_n(x)=1-x^n$. It is monotonous increasing and bounded by $g(x)=1$. Using that the sequence of functions $(x^n)_n$ doesn't converge uniformly in $[0,1]$, we show $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly either.

Comment: Which is the question refering to?

Comment: @continental I think pointwise convergence as well.